# Not able to access images within WEBContent/WEB-INF

Tags: java, zk, fisheye

My project hierarchy is like this.

ProjectName--> WebContent-->WEB-->INF-->ZUL-->XYZ-->images(Folder)+abc.zul

--> when I wants to access image within images folder in abc.zul(which is also inside XYZ fodler) images are not loaded.i am accessing images like this.

image="/images/app_icon.png"

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be **WEB-INF** instead of WEB->INF.

Any resource inside the **WEB-INF** can be accessed programmatically only.

You can put images folder out of the WEB-INF and under WebContent folder in order to access images as  **image="/images/app_icon.png"**.

Again it depends on your requirement and implementation.